# Using database.ini versus hardcoding/using env with psycopg2

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I have a problem that gave me a lot of grievance and would like to understand why it happened.

I want to access our Redshift instance using `psycopg2`. My initial attempt just hardcoded the information in the script and used an env variable for the password.

```
import psycopg2
import os

def connect_to_db():
    return psycopg2.connect(
        host="host url",
        database="db name",
        user="username",
        password=os.getenv("db_pw"),
        port=12345
    )
```

Whenever I tried this, I would get this error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::ffff:<host IP>", user "username", database "db name", SSL off
```

However if I use this following project structure I'm able to get the script to run as intended.

```
- project
    - db.py
    - database.ini
```

And these are the files:

db.py:

```
import psycopg2
from configparser import ConfigParser, Error

def config(filename='database.ini', section='postgresql'):
    # create a parser
    parser = ConfigParser()
    # read config file
    parser.read(filename)

    # get section, default to postgresql
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

    return db


def connect_to_db():
    """Connect to db and return the connection object"""
    params = config()
    return psycopg2.connect(**params)
```

database.ini

```
[postgresql]
host=hosturl
database=db
user=user
password=password
port=12345
```

Could someone explain why this is happening?

Mac Intel 2020 2.3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7

Comment: "My initial attempt just hardcoded the information in the script and used an env variable for the password." except the code you show isn't using an environment variable, it's using a hard-coded password. Perhaps that was the issue? Were you not reading the environment variable correctly?

Comment: @MarkB thanks for that. No that was just me putting in information here to remove any PII.

Comment: Both of these methods are eventually making the same API calls to connect to the database. I has to be an invalid value/typo somewhere in one of the settings that was causing the initial problem. I would double check that the environment variable have the correct value without any spaces at the end or anything, and that the Python code was correctly reading the environment variable.

Comment: That's the issue. I was copy-pasting the pw. Whether it was hardcoded into the script or as an env variable, it wouldn't work. The only way to make it work was the database.ini file.